# Multiple Items Same Shipping Consignment in Magento

Tags: php, magento, fulfillment

Say I have products 1, 2 and 3. They can all be sent in the same consignment, but with a maximum of 5 per consignment. How do I set it up so that the checkout recognizes this and only applies the shipping once to all of them (max 5)?

For example: One consignment can have 5 items but only from a specific manufacturer. So the shipping cost for 1 item is the same as the cost for 5 items. But 6 items will need to be sent in two consignments so the price is doubled.

> 1-5 items, £10.00
>
> 6-11 items, 20.00 ..

Comment: are you talking about applying shipping costs, or creating multiple Shipments per Order?

Comment: Please provide more details and step by step.

Comment: Shipping costs. See question for example

Answer (score 2):

It is a pity, but there is no free extension for such purpose. But if you don't care too much about money, you may use this one:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/webshopapps/extension/1357/webshopapps-product-matrix-shipping

I am not a developer of this extension, but I have used it on one of my projects. It gives you all the functionality available in native table rates + you can define "Shipping Group", that is an attribute on product level. This attribute could help you with grouping of shipping prices per consignment.

Answer (score 1):

with the owebia shipping extension you can have conditions for a lot of things, including the number of items, maybe it can help you: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/owebia/extension/1101/owebia-shipping-2

Comment: My magento shop should charge $15 for every 4 items with the same attribute. This FREE extension has saved my day. It's hard to believe that this is free.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to achieve this with table rates.

In *System > Configuration > Shipping Methods > Table Rates* pick a website or store in the *Current Configuration Scope* then change the "Condition" to "# of Items vs. Destination". Export a CSV. In the CSV column for "# of Items" add the values "1", "6", "11", etc.. and the matching price for each, "10", "20", "30", etc. The other columns can all be "*".

Comment: Can this be restricted to certain prodicts? Also I can't find the Export CSV link? Thanks

Comment: Using this simple method it cannot. The export button only shows when you have used the "Current Configuration Scope" drop-down.